# How do I rename a bot in Slack

Tags: slack, bot

I've added Trello to my Slack team but for some reason it's called "trello2", which is harmless, yet annoying.

How do I rename a Slack bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the most elegant answer, but it worked for me ...

It seems that the name "trello" can't be used as both a bot name and a channel name at the same time.

What I did was I renamed my channel "board" and my bot "trello"

If you come up with a better solution, I'd love to hear about it.